# View beneath a Layout that contains s ScrollView pops up above keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout(vertcial) that hosts a ScrollView and a FrameLayout(beneath the scrollview) which is a button.
In the ScrollView, I have some LinearLayout that I add certain views to - one of them has an EditText. When I hit the EditText and the keyboard pops up, the FrameLayout(the button) is always on top of the keyboard.

I tried setting `android:isScrollContainer="false"` in the ScrollView but that didn't help.
I also tried different `android:windowSoftInputMode` options , but that didn't help either.

```
<RelativeLayout..
....

 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myButtonThatAlwaysPopsUP!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
.....

 <LinearLayout
        android:above="@id/myButtonThatAlwaysPopsUP
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

              <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:scrollbars="none" >
........
```

Comment: Post your *xml code* please.

Comment: @jaydroider I've edited the post